# Should the word "or" be exclusive or inclusive when stating a theorem?

Tags: logic

Let $X$ and $Y$ be arbitrary sets. Further, let $X'\subset X$ and $Y', Y''\subset Y$, where and $Y'\neq Y''$. I am currently stating (and proving) a theorem of the form
\begin{gather}
x\in X'\Leftrightarrow (y\in Y')\vee(y\in Y'')
\end{gather}

I am, however, writing this theorem in English. Hence, I am currently writing
\begin{gather}
\textit{x belongs to X if and only if y belongs to Y' or YY''}
\end{gather}
Since the symbol $\vee$ is inclusive and the English "**or**" is exclusive, I do not know whether I should instead write
\begin{gather}
\textit{x belongs to X if and only if y belongs to Y' or YY'' or both}
\end{gather}

So, when stating a formal theorem in English, should "**or**" keep its English exclusive meaning, or should it adopt the inclusive meaning of the symbol $\vee$?

Comment: You will confuse everybody if you use "or" exclusively. If you mean exclusive-or, you should say so explicitly with "exactly one of the following is true" or words to that effect. If you feel squeamish, you could say "if and only if $y$ belongs to $Y'$ or $YY''$ (or both)" with brackets, but I would strongly expect "or" to be read inclusively.

Comment: [Previous discussion on this issue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3721756/is-the-or-statement-always-inclusive-in-mathematics#comment7650096_3721756)

Comment: If it helps resolve the uncertainty, I think it's simply not true that "or" is always exclusive in English. Example, after dinner when dining out: "Would you like coffee or dessert?"

Comment: Okay, thank you all for your comments. I got it. :)

Comment: "*should "or" keep its English exclusive meaning*"   I'm don't think that "either...or" is usually exclusionary: "if you've visited either Bangkok or Chiang Mai, then you've visited Thailand" doesn't feel to me like an unusual construction involving "either...or".